# How to expand and collapse an array of single-characters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am working with data (a long string) that for some reason has been mutated into an array of single-characters.  Here's an example of it:

```
['f', 'o', 'o', ' ', 't', 'e', 's','t', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```

I need to perform some regex, search/replace on this as a normal string.  So I need to convert it into the normal

```
'foo test bar'
```

... perform some mutations on this, for example replacing "test" with "hi", and then return it to its former state:

```
['f', 'o', 'o', ' ', 'h', 'i' ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```

I suppose coming from a C++ background, I want to treat this string of `char` as a `char*` without some expensive operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array to convert it to a string. [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the word `test`. And convert it back to an array of characters using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

```js
const array = ['f', 'o', 'o', ' ', 't', 'e', 's', 't', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r'],
      output = Array.from(array.join('').replace('test', 'hi'));

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **.join()** to convert array to string, for example:

```
let  str =['f', 'o', 'o', ' ', 't', 'e', 's','t', ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r'].join(" "));

//return 'foo test bar'
```

then you replace String with **.replace**, for example:

```
str.replace('test','hi');
```

also you use **.split("")** to convert string to array, for example:

```
console.log('foo test bar'..split(""));

//return ['f', 'o', 'o', ' ', 'h', 'i' ' ', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```